# android TCP socket (Check if available)

Tags: android, sockets

I have an android app that connects to a TCP server.
I made a button to check is the server is available.
If i click the button it keeps trying to connect and doesn't go to the Exception.

Code:

```
try {
    Socket s = new Socket("192.168.xxx.xx",xxxxx);
    available = true;
    s.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //show error toast.
}
```

Comment: So your goal really is to check for an internet connection?

Comment: Dont think so as 192.168.xxx.xx has nothing to do with internet. Think OP has to set a time out value.